# Save Key or String securely in app - Xamarin Form

Tags: c#, android, ios, api, xamarin.forms

I’ve been following various articles and answers regarding saving
API keys / password / strings still havent gotten specifically that i have been searching.

The idea is to save KEY in a form of string in Xamarin.Form
where the KEY can be accessed while debugging
but should not be exposed if reversed engineered an APK or IPA file.

Stated by one of my colleague ‘Gradle’ used to do similar in android native
yet am unsure on it and where do i get it working in Xamarin.Forms with respect to iOS and Android

Any information related would be much helpful

Comment: if i understand you correctly.. you want to save some information in your app. in a way that the app has access to it, but anyone with access to the app doesn't?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Yes..exactly!!! but i dont want the String/Key to be exposed via APK or IPA file if reversed engineered

Comment: that is logically impossible. everyone who has access to the app, also has access to what the app can access. think about it: no matter how hidden and encrypted the key is, at _some_ point the app needs to have it as plain text, so it can actually use it. you can make it harder for an attacker by hiding, encrypting and obfuscating, but you can't make it so hard that it's not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to make use of [SecureStorage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?tabs=ios) this will use the platform specific secure stores to store the data you provide.

As pointed out in comments you should always operate under the assumption that someone will be able to gain access to your code and reverse engineer it. Using the secure stores per platform will require that anyone accessing the device will be able to unlock it via PIN or biometrics, depending on the device.

Comment: Thanks for the update Bijington and my apologies for the late reply, I have followed the link that you have given but the method is not being accepted by my work colleagues. I have followed one of the forums that have been used. https://admcpr.com/keeping-secrets-out-of-your-source-code-with-mobile-buildtools-and-appcenter/